# How to update the UI thread with Task.Factory.StartNew?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, task-parallel-library

I have the following code, but it does not initially update the UI thread.  Am I doing something wrong?

```
Protected Sub Copy_OnClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    StatusLabel.Text = "Processing..." 'This doesn't happen
    Copy.Enabled = False 'This doesn't happen

    Dim copyTask As Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() Copy())

    copyTask.Wait()

    If (copyTask.IsCompleted) Then
        Copy.Enabled = True
        StatusLabel.Text = "Done" 'This happens     
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are waiting on the UI thread. Why are you starting a task and then immediately waiting for it? That conceptually doesn't make sense.

Use one of the standard techniques for unblocking the UI thread.

Comment: I wasn't completely sure what Wait did, but your answer clarified it for me.  When you say standard technique, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean whatever comes out when you search for ".net unblock ui thread". The answer depends on your .net version and what exactly you want to do.